# How to prepend/add a "03" infront of hexString of a byte array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, hex

Suppose I have a byte array

```
byte [] initial = ......;
```

And it's corresponding hex string is 0x6b6164756d ,i.e;

```
System.out.println(Numeric.toHexString(initial)); //--> 0x6b6164756d
```

How to add "03" in front of "initial" so that when I

```
System.out.println(Numeric.toHexString(initial)); //--> 0x036b6164756d
```

it gives me 0x036b6164756d

Comment: `0xfr123444` is an invalid hex number

Comment: @Reimeus thanks for the comment, I just decided on the hex string in a hurry. But I have updated the hex string now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Insert a `byte` with value 3 in front.

   ```java
   byte[] copy = new byte[initial.length + 1];
   copy[0] = 0x03;
   System.arraycopy(initial, 0, copy, 1, initial.length);
   System.out.println(Numeric.toHexString(copy));
   ```
2. Modify the string.

   ```java
   System.out.println(Numeric.toHexString(initial).replace("x", "x03"));
   ```